# Issue in publishing Microsoft bot v4 designed with Adaptive dialog

Tags: botframework, adaptive-dialogs

I am working with Microsoft bot framework `4.10` with adaptive card. my bot properly working in emulator, but when I tried to publish it in `Azure` web app its not given any response as expected. I have go through Microsoft given both samples. Take a look at the [github project](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt).

I have done the same configurations as in the document.

Is there any additional configurations needed to be done for adaptive dialog.

I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, which documentation are you referring to publish the bot to Azure?

Comment: @ranusharao, Thank you for your reply, Now i can able to publish my bot in azure. But i don't get any response from bot. I have referred above given solution.

Comment: Does 'Test in Web Chat' work as expected?

Comment: @ranusharao, it is working only in bot emulator. when i publish the bot api in azure, i didn't get any response in webchat and directline.

Comment: What error are you getting in the Channels tab on Azure? Can you double check if you missed out on any step in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp? and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0